# How do I make my popup image that is fetched from imgur be responsive?

Tags: image, responsive

I'm having trouble making my popup-image responsive
I tried to solve it for many hours but to no avail
Can anyone spot any issue within my code?

https://pastebin.com/5DUdJptp

https://jsfiddle.net/mcs29L9p/

Please check the pastebin or jsfiddle for the full code

```
#popup-box 
{
      display:none;
      position:absolute;
      //border:solid 1px #f5f5f5;
      //background:#fff;
      //box-shadow:0 0 10px #666;
      left:0;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      right:0;
      margin:auto;

      width: 600px;
      height: 600px;          
}

#popup-image
{
    width:100%; 
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: why pastebin and not a real example using jsfiddle or an equivalent ?

Comment: in css, comments are `/* ... */`, double slashes `//` won't work.

Comment: yes, Will edit. Newbie here :) Thanks

Comment: I added jsfiddle please kindly see the code if you have spare time

Answer (score 0):

First, jsfiddle comes with different "editors" for css, html and js. Please, don't put everything in the html view (see the fiddle below for an example).

For your question, you hard-code the size of your `#popup-box` with the `width` and `height` attributes, this is why it does not adapt. One simple fix is to use `max-width` and `max-height` instead:

```
#popup-box {
  /* ... */
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 600px;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcs29L9p/1/) for a complete example.

---

*As a side note*: making a website responsive is a lot of work. Hopefully, many css frameworks can take care of that for you: bootstrap, semantic-ui, material to name a few. If you are creating a production site, I suggest you switch to one of them instead of reinventing the wheel.